# Regarding the mysql performance while using AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two table where the data in the tables will be removed and again inserted with updated values when called from java application.
My doubt is I have given `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for each table with some size,
(please find below) but the present table count is very less.
Is this will effect MySQL performance ?

`select count(*) from t_p1;` -- 23400 but the (AUTO_INCREMENT=8690591) and

`select count(*) from me1 ;` -- 73 but the (AUTO_INCREMENT=45706)

Comment: Why not use `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY` rather than the delete/insert cycle?

Comment: Yes, the performance issue that auto increment brings is most likely a lot less than delete/insert cycle vs update

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` is also an option with MySQL. You have a lot of ways to go here. What I don't know is what your issue is. Unless you're doing benchmarks or have hard data from your production system then it's really hard to say what your performance problems are.

Comment: My issue is if we have large AUTO_INCREMENT value and the actual data in table is less when compared to AUTO_INCREMENT value.whether this will effect any mysql performance while using this tables in any stored procedure?

Comment: Only way to find out is to benchmark.